# Calling an Oracle function from SQL Server Linked Server - input parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have setup a linked server pointing to an Oracle database. I want to call a function ABC in a package XYZ passing parameter K. What will be the syntax to do this?

How to enter parameters to function?

Here is my routine where I call the Oracle function

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateProject] (@ProjectBudgetId INT)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Value varchar(1000)
DECLARE @Adress varchar(1000) = 'https://dev.local/front/form/39449d5c-705a-487d-a115-db50910fe200/1'


EXECUTE 
('
DECLARE 
v_numer VARCHAR2(200);
v_id NUMBER;
p_link_EOD VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN
v_numer := TETA_ADMIN.API_NAX_PROJEKTY_KLN.wyznacz_nr_projektu(''Projekt_test'', SYSDATE);

p_link_EOD := @Adress

v_id :=  TETA_ADMIN.API_NAX_PROJEKTY_KLN.dodaj_projekt (
''Projekt_test'',
v_numer,
''Oppo'',
''Numr zewnetrzny, np. POWER/64548763 itd'',
To_Date(''01012021'',''ddmmyyyy''), 
To_Date(''31122021'',''ddmmyyyy''),
''PLN'',
10254000,
NULL,
''Testowy typ projektu'',
''Testowy rodzaj projektu'',
''Opis słowno-muzyczny, czyli co w projekcie będzie robione'',
NULL,
p_link_EOD);

COMMIT;
? := v_id;

END;', @Adress, @Value OUTPUT) AT TETAATH


UPDATE [bud].[ProjectBudget]
SET [BudgetTETAId] = @Value
WHERE Id = @ProjectBudgetId

END
```

Comment: You can't parametrise dynamic statemens apart from with `sys.sp_executesql` (this is why `EXECUTE (@SQL)` syntax is generally not recommended), and that won't work for what you want here. You'll need to ***SAFELY*** inject the parameters into a dynamic statement, and then execute that statement, You don't, however, be able to use an `OUTPUT` parameter at all.

Comment: How should I enter the parameters? What syntax to use? And what about the result? Because after calling the function, I need the Id of the created record?

Comment: As I mentioned, you'll need to ***SAFELY*** (**emphasis**) inject the parameters. As for the ID, as I also mentioned, you can't use an `OUTPUT` parameter, so you'll need to use a `SELECT` and capture it that way.

Comment: And could I ask for an example?

Comment: I'm not an Oracle developer, so I wouldn't want to make any assumptions on the syntax for that.

Comment: But I do it from the side of the sql server, not oracle

Comment: But I don't know what the Oracle code inside the dynamic statement should be, @mrub; I'm not an Oracle Developer (like I mentioned). As a result i can't provide a solution as no doubt I'll make assumptions about how Oracle works, get them wrong, and then you'll expect me to "support" those errors.